# How to create webservice to connect android with microsoft sql server database?

Tags: android, web-services

I want to create webservice which will do logical operations such read,write,insert,update records from SQL server database and returns the response in json object.

After reading that responses I want update the values in android local SQLite database......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build it yourself, you can write an HTTP Post Request method in a class. As the request, a post item "request" can carry the value. This can be "read", "write", "insert", "update", "collect all records", "delete them all", .. etc. With other parameter, you can send other details.

You haven't specified the language you will use for webservice. It probably will be ASP.NET, since you are using SQL Server. So on "onload" request, you can take the details from "Request" attribute and according to value of "request", you route the webservice to a method. And that method connects to SQL Server, completes the request and returns back to Android.

Comment: @ tcak your right that webservice in ASP.NET, But how to write webservice in ASP.NET? I haven't used webservices before....If you have any links or tutorials please help me on this

Comment: Since this method is a custom webservice, if you already know how to create an ASP.NET page, there is no difference. Create a normal ASP.NET page. When the request comes to the page, check the POST request. if(Request.Form['request'] == 'insert') callInsertMethod(); And that method connects to DB. Then you can build the SQL with form data. SQL = 'insert into users(' + Request.Form['firstname'] + ')'; According the query results, write JSON message to output. {"results": "successful", "count": "5"} DONE.

Comment: @ tcak can I write this webservice in Java or I have to write to write in only ASP.NET since I haven't used ASP.NET before

Comment: As far as I understand from you first question, you will use Java for Android programming. For Android side, you only need a method to send HTTP Post requests, that's all. There is nothing complex. By your last question, I understand that you want a Java webservice to take request, connect to SQL Server, and return back. Well, you can develop a JSP (Java Servlet) page with completely same logic as I explained. There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Google "REST web service Java." You should get by with that.